# R data.table: label the counts of consecutive non-NA values

Tags: r, label, data.table

Here is the data.table I have, with the column `column1`.

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(column1 = c(NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, "1 2", "1 2", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, ...))

> print(dt)
    column1
 1:      NA
 2:      NA
 3:       A
 4:       A
 5:       A
 6:      NA
 7:      NA
 8:      NA
 9:      NA
10:       B
11:      NA
12:      NA
13:     1 2
14:     1 2
15:      NA
16:      NA
17:       A
18:       A
19:       A
20:       A
21:       A
22:      NA
23:      NA
24:      NA
25:      NA
...     ...
```

The values in `column1` are either NA values or characters. I would like to label each consecutive group of non-NA values by number of items within this group. Here is what the intended for `dt$labels`

```
> print(dt)
    column1    labels
 1:      NA    0 
 2:      NA    0 
 3:       A    3 
 4:       A    3 
 5:       A    3    
 6:      NA    0 
 7:      NA    0  
 8:      NA    0
 9:      NA    0 
10:       B    1 
11:      NA    0 
12:      NA    0  
13:     1 2    2  
14:     1 2    2  
15:      NA    0 
16:      NA    0 
17:       A    5  
18:       A    5  
19:       A    5  
20:       A    5     
21:       A    5    
22:      NA    0  
23:      NA    0 
24:      NA    0   
25:      NA    0   
...     ...    ...
```

There are 3 consecutive A's, 1 "B", 2 "1 2", and 5 "A"s.

Using `rle()` with

```
x <- rle(dt$column1)
```

will give the lengths for each unique value

```
 Run Length Encoding                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   lengths: int [1:18] 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   values : chr [1:18] NA NA "A" NA NA NA NA "B" NA NA "1 2" ...
```

but I'm not sure how to map these lengths to the data.table column `labels`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create a grouping variable and then multiply the logical vector with `.N` and assign (`:=`) the output to 'labels'

```
dt[, labels := .N*!is.na(column1), rleid(is.na(column1))]
dt
#    column1 labels
# 1:      NA      0
# 2:      NA      0
# 3:       A      3
# 4:       A      3
# 5:       A      3
# 6:      NA      0
# 7:      NA      0
# 8:      NA      0
# 9:      NA      0
#10:       B      1
#11:      NA      0
#12:      NA      0
#13:     1 2      2
#14:     1 2      2
#15:      NA      0
#16:      NA      0
#17:       A      5
#18:       A      5
#19:       A      5
#20:       A      5
#21:       A      5
#22:      NA      0
#23:      NA      0
#24:      NA      0
#25:      NA      0
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(column1 = c(NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", 
  NA, NA, "1 2", "1 2", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Akrun's answer works well when there are no values in column1 that are repeated after the NA. For example (note the only difference is i change the two NA's proceeding the first "B" with "A"s):

```
dt <- data.table(column1 = c(NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", "B", 
                         NA, NA, "1 2", "1 2", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

In order to make sure that the first set of consecutive "A"s are all in the same group, the following (slight modification) of code will work:

```
dt[!is.na(column1), labels:=rleid(column1), rleid(is.na(column1))]
```

The output is as follows:

```
        column1 labels
 1:    <NA>     NA
 2:    <NA>     NA
 3:       A      1
 4:       A      1
 5:       A      1
 6:    <NA>     NA
 7:    <NA>     NA
 8:       A      1
 9:       A      1
10:       B      2
11:    <NA>     NA
12:    <NA>     NA
13:     1 2      3
14:     1 2      3
15:    <NA>     NA
16:    <NA>     NA
17:       A      4
18:       A      4
19:       A      4
20:       A      4
21:       A      4
22:    <NA>     NA
23:    <NA>     NA
24:    <NA>     NA
25:    <NA>     NA
```

To replace NA's with zero: `dt[is.na(labels), labels:=0]`